# display: inline-block doesn't work on ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax, css

When I receive response from my script I create new elements and attach them to my main container, but these new elements doesn't respect the "display: inline-block" property, I tried to embed the style on the html but it doesn't work either.

Here's my code

```
jQuery.post('includes/script.php', {GetMore: true}, function(data) {
    dato = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    $.each(dato, function(i){
        var html = '<div class="container_'+ dato[i][1] +'" data-img="'+dato[i][2]+'" data-order="'+dato[i][3]+'" style="display: inline-block">'+
                   '<img src="'+dato[i][0]+'" class="img_'+ dato[i][1] +'" />'+
                   '</div>';
        $('div#main-container').append(html);
    });
});
```

Comment: Might be as simple as having a space between div and #maincontainer?

Comment: You should post your style definitions too.

Comment: It isn't possible to determine whether there's an issue with your JSON object or the selector you use to append the HTML from here. You'll have to give us more information or try to replicate this on a small scale.

Answer (score 0):

When any element is set display to inline-block **then browser place a 'white space' at right side of this element**.

When you insert this kind of elements with ajax seems it doesn't take place.

I had this problem too. **I ended up with adding this 'white space' by myself.** In your case you should change your code like:

```
var html = '&nbsp;<div class="container_'+ ....
```

Anyway you should insert **nbsp;** between elements which you receive through ajax.